# How to change a css style each page in vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

This is App.vue File

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <main-header/>
    <router-view/>
    <main-footer/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MainHeader from './components/layouts/MainHeader'
  import MainFooter from './components/layouts/MainFooter'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      'main-header': MainHeader,
      'main-footer': MainFooter
    }
  }
</script>
```

Header.vue file is

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="active" href="/">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/test1">
            test1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/test2">
            test2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to activate "active class" differently for each page.
I don't know how to do

if I click a "test2", active class have to maintain only with the tag with "test2"
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If '<router-link>' is used, that a `<router-link>` automatically gets the `.router-link-active` class when its target route is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [Vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) with `active-class` prop

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
  <router-link to="/" tag="li" class="dropdown" active-class="active">Home</router-link>
  <router-link to="/test1" tag="li" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" active-class="active">Test1</router-link>
  <router-link to="/test2" tag="li" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" active-class="active">Test2</router-link>
</ul>
```

Another naive solution is checking `window.location.href`, but it's not simple to cover all possible cases.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mainNav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="active" href="/">
            Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/test1" :class="getClass('/test1')">
            test1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="/test2" :class="getClass('/test2')">
            test2
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    getClass(url) {
      if (window.location.href.includes(url)) {
        return "active"
      }
      return ""
    }
  }
}
</script>
```